# Video ports on motherboard dont function

Tags: video, motherboard

I build a custom computer. All the fans are functional, I installed everything and can not get a display on any monitor. I tried with the video card and without. I used several different functional monitors and a HD Television with the same results.

How does one know if the motherboard is fried? 
How can I determine the problem?

Comment: Make sure the MB speaker is hooked up. There will be various patterns of long and short beeps documented in the motherboard manual for different errors.